# Image paths in SASS file which has been included?

Tags: sass

Im my project I have a main SASS file in the root. I also have a folder with _other.sass and icon.png in it.

```
main.sass
folder/_other.sass
folder/icon.png
```

My main SASS file includes my other SASS file:

In main.sass:

```
@include 'folder/other'
```

In _other.sass:

```
div {
    background: url(icon.png);
}
```

Should the path to the image resolve correctly in this case? From the point of view of _other.sass the path is correct, but its not correct relative to main.sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the compiled code will be included in your final `*.css` file, all urls must be relative to that resulting `*.css` file. In the code you have posted, the url is assigned as regular css code, so it wont be transformed in any way.

If you would use [compass](http://compass-style.org/), what is a great extension to sass, you can use the provided functions, f. i. [those](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/) to generate the needed urls. With compass you can configure all the base paths and the stuff alike, sass itself wont do that for you.